# Query with AND condition returning true even on wrong parameter

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

The following query is returning 1 even when I provide wrong username, it is just comparing the password why?

```
conn.ConnectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CoreConnection").ConnectionString
conn.Open()

cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select count(1) from admin where userid=@userid and password=@password", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text)
Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar

conn.Close()

If (result > 0) Then
    'MessageBox.Show("Success")
    ad.Show()
Else
    MsgBox("Invalid username or Password!")
End If
```

Comment: Isn't ExecuteScalar a method? I don't know vb syntax but may be add parenthesis?

Comment: Even after the parenthesis the result is same, I think the problem is in the Parameters because if i provide the hardcoded username and password it works fine but not with parameters

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1) say that named parameters are not supported (although I seem to recall them working anyway), so try using `?` for the parameters in your SQL - e.g. `select count(1) from admin where userid=? and password=?`.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Have you tried replacing Textbox1.Text with the actual string you want to pass in (and the same for Textbox2.Text). That should help determine whether it is indeed the parameters (although I think it highly unlikely)